# Answer to this probability problem: $ \frac 1 { 24 } $ or $ \frac 5 { 24 } $?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Find the marginal densities of $ X $ and $ Y $ from the following joint density function and verify that marginal distributions are also probability distributions.
> $$ f _ { X , Y } ( x , y ) = \begin {cases}
> \frac 1 8 ( 6 - x - y ) \text , & \text {for } 0 < x < 2 \text {, } 2 < y < 4 \\
> 0 \text , & \text {otherwise}
> \end {cases} $$
> Also compute $ \Pr ( X + Y < 3 ) $ and $ \Pr ( X < 1.5 , Y < 2.5 ) $

I would like to know the answer of the second question ($ \Pr ( X + Y < 3 ) $) here.
My answer came out to be $ \frac 5 { 24 } $ but my teacher is arguing that it is $ \frac 1 { 24 } $.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my solution

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It would be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, how you got till your answer, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my solution.

Comment: Next time, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pictures.

Comment: Yes, sure. Actually this was my first time using this site.

Comment: No one expects you to learn everything when you're new to this site. Besides, it would be cruel for people to downvote without explaining. If you hover over the downvote arrow, you'll see a very brief explanation that says: "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" but isn't actually that helpful.

Comment: Your question is better than 90% of first-time users from what I've seen, and it's currently voted at +2/-5 for a total score of -3 (remember, upvotes count for 10 rep). Keep on asking good questions and you'll get there ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a small mistake in the limits of the outer integral, the upper limit should be a 2 instead of a 1. This gives a final answer of $\frac{1}{24}$.

See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286%283-x%29-12-x%283-x%29%2B2x-%283-x%29%5E2%2F2%2B2%29%2F8+dx+from+0+to+2

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if I allow x to be up to 2, wouldn't that cause y to be 3-2 = 1? but in the question given, the function gives a non-zero output for 2 < y < 4

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3jlezggls7

Answer (score 1):

As per @Jacobiman answer, you made a mistake on the upper limit of the outer integral where the upper limit should be 2 rather than 1. This is because your $D_{x} =(0,2)$. It shouldn't be 1 because your $R_{y} = (2,4)$ and $1 \notin (2,4)$. So the answer is $\frac{1}{24}$.

P.S. I can't comment since I don't have enough reputation so I got to make another answer :(

Comment: If x is 2 then y = 1 and 1 doesn't belong to (2,4)

Comment: Yea, so there will be no value in wrt y. But your outer integral is wrt x, so your integral limits should be from 0 to 2

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: But, if my outer limits are 0 to 2, for x = 2 the inner limit for y will be y=2 to y=3-x = 3-2 = 1. But y should be within 2 and 4 right?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with univariate integrals. For double integrals, you must keep in mind that your inner integral is a function of x since you are integrating wrt y first.

Comment: @MehbubulHasanAlQuvi: If this answer has resolved your question, you should accept it.